# Identifying 'effective' unit tests for a service facade

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Given the following (basic) service facade class, I'd like some recommendations and guidance on what unit tests should and are worth writing.  I am using MEF for dependency injection and AutoMapper for object-to-object mapping of my data contracts to domain objects and vice versa.

```
public sealed class MyServiceFacade
{
    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public MyServiceFacade(IDependency dependency,
                           IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
        if (dependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dependency");

        if (mappingEngine == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mappingEngine");

        Dependency = dependency;
        MappingEngine = mappingEngine;
    }

    public IDependency Dependency { get; private set; }
    public IMappingEngine MappingEngine { get; private set; }

    public ResponseContract TheMethod(RequestContract requestContract)
    {
        // Verify parameters
        if (requestContract == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(requestContract);

        // Translate parameter values
        var request = MappingEngine.DynamicMap<Request>(requestContract);

        // Delegate to the domain layer
        var response = Dependency.DoSomethingWith(request);

        // Translate the response
        var responseContract = MappingEngine.DynamicMap<ResponseContract>(response);

        // Return the response
        return responseContract;
    }
}
```

I'd like to see good code coverage but don't want to write tests that aren't useful/effective.

(Suggestions on effective integration tests would be helpful as well.)

Your thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Based on the limited responses, I thought I go ahead and steer the conversation a bit more (something I tried to avoid originally) by describing what I consider the 'worst case' scenario.

One of the devs on my team is a strong advocate for 'white box' unit testing with as much code coverage as possible. As a result of his approach, we'd have the following tests:

1. When the object is constructed, if the 'dependency' property is null, an ArgumentNullException is thrown.
2. When the object is constructed, if the 'mappingEngine' property is null, an ArgumentNullException is thrown.
3. When the object is constructed, if both arguments are not null, an ArgumentNullException is not thrown.
4. After the object is constructed, the Dependency property returns the object passed in the 'dependency' parameter to the constructor.
5. After the object is constructed, the MappingEngine property returns the object passed in the 'mappingEngine' parameter to the constructor.
6. When TheMethod is called, if the 'requestContract' property is null, an ArgumentNullException is thrown.
7. When TheMethod is called, if the 'requestContract' property is not null, an ArgumentNullException is not thrown.
8. When TheMethod is called, the DynamicMap() method of the mocked IMappingEngine is called only once with the RequestContract passed to TheMethod.
9. When TheMethod is called, the DoSomethingWith() method of the mocked IDependency is called only once with the Request object returned from the mocked IMappingEngine.
10. When TheMethod is called, the DynamicMap() method of the mocked IMappingEngine is called only once with the Response object returned from the mocked IDependency.
11. When TheMethod is called, the ResponseContract object returned from the mocked IMappingEngine is returned.

As you can see, this results in a large number of tests that really are testing the implementation and do not reflect the higher level requirements (another approach on the table).

Is this how you approach testing or would you go a different route?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like some recommendations and guidance on what unit tests should and are worth writing

I use [equivalence partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) to suggest a set of basic tests that provide good coverage.

Comment: Equivalence partitioning in testing has some drawbacks though. It doesn't properly check for boundary conditions. Rather than using a technique like this one, personally, I use my brain to decide how many unit-tests are needed and what they should cover :)

Comment: @Guillaume, since it's been a long week I'm opting to not consider your comment an insult and ask both of you to provide more tangible details. While I'd like to understand the thought process behind the approach, I'm not looking for a computer science lesson and put the code sample in the original post so there would be something concrete as the basis for response.

Comment: This is a typical use-case in my organization that draws a lot of discussion and differences of opinions in what should and should be tested. The purpose of my post is to open this to a large audience to see what the community at-large has to say on this subject.

Comment: Oh sorry I realise that must sound harsh, it was not my intent at all (English is not my natural language), so I really apologize if it sounded like an insult, I know it's an open discussion, I just meant to say I'm not following any specific philosophy for deciding what tests to write. Again, apologies :(

Comment: @Guillaume: equivalence partitioning is a 2ay of "using your brain". But rather than just randomly selecting test cases, it is a more systematic approach for selecting test cases that are "worth writing".

Comment: @Son of Pirate: what do you want to know that is not covered by the Wikipedia page I linked to?

Comment: A tangible example of how you would apply equivalence partitioning to the above code example. In other words, applying that approach, what tests would you write for the sample class/method?

Comment: @SonOfPirate: I'm not going to write your test code for you. I've given you "some recommendations and guidance": learn about equivalence partitioning.

Comment: Believe me, everyone here has read the Wikipedia article and others on the subject as well as countless other reference sources. The purpose of this site is to get tangible answers so we can better understand how to apply those concepts.  If you aren't willing to write YOUR test code for the sample, then let's just leave it with appreciation for the link.

Comment: I should clarify (and am updating the main post as well) that I am not looking for you to write the actual test code but explain what tests you would right and why. Again, the theory has been explained (by your link), but I'm looking for you would apply the theory.